# Can all inputs of an op amp be used?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am asking myself if all inputs (non inverting and inverting ones) can be used.

For example, having an LM4562 that has two non inverting inputs and two inverting inputs, with 4 outputs as well, 2 non inverting and 2 inverting, which will the circuit be if using all of them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LM4562 is a dual Op-Amp. Essentially it has 2 separate Op-Amps in the same package. It has 2 inputs for the first one, and 2 inputs for the second. Each has its own output.

It only has 2 outputs, not 4.

Inverting and non inverting input A work with output A, whereas inverting and non inverting input B work with output B

Comment: Oh, I miss understood the datasheet. Thank you!

Comment: @Nayara No problem!

Answer (score 0):

An operational amplifier (op-amp or opamp) has only five connections:

- Non-inverting input ('+')
- Inverting input ('-')
- Output
- Positive supply (sometimes 'V+')
- Negative supply (sometimes 'V-')

An op-amp doesn't have any more than this.

Your LM4562 doesn't either. It's got two op-amps in one 8-pin package, which share the same power supply pins. See below diagram from their [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4562.pdf?ts=1690913782087).

What might be confusing you is the terminology used by Texas Instruments for the LM4562 on their [product webpage][2] and datasheet:

"2-channel, 55-MHz, high-fidelity, high performance audio op amp"

That's bad terminology from TI: it's not a two-channel op-amp, it's two op-amps.

[image]

Comment: Things like a reference voltage source for multiple constant current sources may well be shared in dual opamps, making it consume less current than two single ones.  In this case, typical/maximal quiescent current for the LM4562 is 10mA/12mA while the same for its single opamp variant LME49710 is 4.8mA/5.5mA.  Which does not exactly support my point, uhm.

Comment: @user107063, quite :-) You can get all sorts of stuff but this isn't one of them, it's just two op-amps in one chip.